# why i cannot cast from button to EditText?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I see in android documentation that `Button` extends `EditText`

but in code I get this error:

```
private Button mInputBox;

    ((EditText))mInputBox).setSelection(s.length());
```

`Cannot cast from Button to EditText`

why is that?

Comment: *Off-topic*: You named your button as *mInputBox*? Why so?

Comment: [Button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) extends  TextView class instead of EditText

Comment: `((EditText))mInputBox).setSelection(s.length());` - note the paren error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Button` extends `TextView` not `EditText`. Casting to `EditText` will cause `ClassCastException`. By the way if you want to cast to the base class you should use `View`.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html
It says on top of page

```
public class

Button

extends TextView
```

Answer (score 1):

Both Button and EditText extends TextView. You cannot cast a Button to EditText.